# PDO Error sintaxis (Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000])

Tags: php, pdo

estoy intentando realizar una consulta y que solo me devuelva los registros que cumplan con una condición, en este caso, que sean de la carrera Desarrollo de Software, pero creo que estoy teniendo problemas con la sintaxis de PDO

```
<?php // Incluimos la conexión a la base de datos y le damos un formato a los datos para poder utilizarlos luego.
    include_once "models/conexion.php";
    $sentencia = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM trabajos_finales WHERE carrera = Desarrollo de Software");
    $trabajos = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>

    <!-- INICIO DE CONTENIDO -->
    <div class="container mb-4">
        <h1 class="fw-bold bg-danger text-white text-center p-3 mt-5 mb-5 fs-3 border border-4 rounded-top">Lista de Trabajos Finales para la carrera de: DESARROLLO DE SOFTWARE</h1>

        <?php include("includes/busqueda.php"); ?>

        <?php // Buscamos lo que se repite y lo metemos en un bucle, se cierra la llave del bucle al final de lo que queramos repetir, dentro de una nueva etiqueta PHP.
            foreach ($trabajos as $trabajo) {
        ?>
        <div class="card mb-5 shadow">
            <div>
                <h5 class="card-header border-danger border-opacity-25"><b><?php echo $trabajo->titulo;?></span></b></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <ul class="list-unstyled pb-2">
                    <li><h6 class="card-title color-azul"><b><i class="fa-solid fa-list pe-1"></i>Tema:</b><span class="ps-1 text-dark fw-light"><?php echo $trabajo->tema;?></span></h6></li>
                    <li><h6 class="card-title color-azul"><b><i class="fa-solid fa-users pe-1"></i>Alumnos:</b><span class="ps-1 text-dark fw-light"><?php echo $trabajo->autor1. ', ' .$trabajo->autor2. ', ' .$trabajo->autor3. ', ' .$trabajo->autor4. ', ' .$trabajo->autor5?></span></h6></li>
                    <li><h6 class="card-title color-azul"><b><i class="fa-solid fa-calendar-check pe-1"></i>Fecha de Aprobación:</b><span class="ps-1 text-dark fw-light"><?php echo $trabajo->fechadeaprobacion;?></span></h6></li>
                    <li><h6 class="card-title color-azul"><b><i class="fa-solid fa-upload pe-1"></i>Fecha de Carga:</b><span class="ps-1 text-dark fw-light"><?php echo $trabajo->fechadecarga;?></span></h6></li>
                </ul>
                <hr>
                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <!-- TRIGGER DE VENTANA MODAL -->
                        <button class="btn btn-danger border border-1 rounded w-25" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info pe-1"></i>Ver más...</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
            } // Acá recién cerramos el bucle.
        ?>
```

cualquier ayuda es agradecida :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tienes problemas con la sintaxis del sql, al parecer olvidaste las comillas para delimitar la cadena.

```
 "SELECT * FROM trabajos_finales WHERE carrera = 'Desarrollo de Software'"
```